# Header location not locating/redirecting as per condition

Tags: php, header

Here I have written that if...else condition with different header location.

```
$a = "yahoo";
if($a == "yahoo")
{
header('location:http://www.yahoo.com');
}else{
header('location:http://www.gmail.com');
}

header('location:http://www.google.com');
```

**Problem:**

In above code if condition is true then also it will redirecting to **`google.com`**

As per my opinion I think its first goes into if condition and then redirect to given location and other below code will not executed.

When I will write **`exit()`** or **`die()`** with every header It will work.

**Question**

Can anyone suggest me where its create issue?

Why without `exit()` or `die()` its not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Location:" header. Not only does it send this header back to the browser, but it also returns a REDIRECT (302) status code to the browser unless the 201 or a 3xx status code has already been set.

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

You can read more about this at the php manual [php header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Answer (score 1):

as you can find in this comment on docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#85254

Headers are **overwriten by themselfs**. Therefore if you do not stop executing your code, your header is changed to 'google' and after that sent to the user..